# Iterate over csv file with While Controller

Tags: while-loop, jmeter

I try to iterate on a `.csv` file with a `While Controller`. I want only one iteration.

The condition used for stop the loop is the follwing one : `${__javaScript(vars.get("TestCaseName") != "")}`

**Thread Group config**

- Number of Threads : 1
- Ramp-Up Period :
- Loop count : 1

**CSV Data Set Config**

- Variable Names : TestCaseName
- Recycle on EOF : False
- Stop thread on EOF : True
- Sharing mode : Current thread

However, an infine loop is generated...

Can you help me please?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put your CSV Data Set Config inside the While Controller
2. Amend the While Controller's condition to use:

   - [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as since JMeter 3.1 you should be using Groovy for scripting
   - [`__jm__While Controller__idx` variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) to stop after the first While Controller's loop

     ```
     ${__groovy(!vars.get("TestCaseName").equals("") && (vars.get("__jm__While Controller__idx") as int) < 1 ,)}
     ```

   [image]

Check out [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter/) for more hints if needed

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, only the first line is read and the thread is finished.

Comment: It is working. I put `1` in `Loop Count` instead of `Forever` in `Thread Group` config... Then what is the difference between `While Controller` and `Loop Controller`? What is the best way to do? Thank you.

Comment: Loop Controller just executes its children for fixed number of times, While Controller allows to put specific condition(s), by default it will loop forever but will exit the loop when/if the specified criteria are met.